# Flutter Group layout

Tags: flutter, user-interface, mobile, layout, flutter-layout

Can anyone point me to a direction where I can achieve a group layout like this picture?
[Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An9wj.png)
I've been trying to do it with a list view but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a Row widgets in Column Widgets in Container or Card widgets in Column Widget.

Here's an example:

```
           Column(
              children: [
                Card(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Column(),
                      Column(),
                      Column(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Card(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Column(),
                      Column(),
                      Column(),
                    ],
                  ),

                ),
              ],
            )
```

Comment: Perfect, definitely pointed me in right direction.